# Error al momento de importar de excel a datagridview

Tags: c#

Estaba tratando de importar unos datos de excel e un datagridview con el siguiente codigo. Funciona con los archivos de excel del 97 al 2003. Pero si intento con una versión de documento superior me marca este error en el  "foreach (DataTable dt in **result.Tables**)" :

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."

Estoy usando exceldatareader version 2.1.2.3

```
DataSet result;
 using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() 
    { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", ValidateNames = true })
                {
                    ofd.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
                    {
                        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            //Read excel file
                            FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                            IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                            reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                            result = reader.AsDataSet();
                            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                            //Add sheet to combobox
                            foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                                comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el tipo de documento de la izquierda al momento de abrirlo si lo abre correctamente mientras que el del lado derecho me marca el error comentado en la parte de arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo que mencionas es .xlsx, el cual el reader debe generarse a partir de `CreateOpenXmlReader`, podrias poner un condicional para saber si es xlsx o xls y a partir de alli generas el reader de una forma u otra.

```
if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper() == ".XLSX")
 IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
else
 IExcelDataReader reader == ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Luciano Montañez ya me funciona con lo que me dices :)!!